# Opening csv files created from Unix in google sheets

Tags: unix, google-sheets

I am generating a csv file in Unix and sending the report to my email. It is working good, if I open the report in Excel from MS Outlook, but recently we moved to Gsuite and the attachment is now showing junk characters, when I open the attachment in Google Sheets from Gmail.

Any idea how to make this work in Gsheet?

In my Unix script, I am using:

```html
uuencode report_data.csv REPORT_DATA_Current.csv) | mailx -s "Todays report - `date +%m-%d-%Y`" $EMAIL_LIST
```

Comment: Welcome. _"the attachment is now showing junk characters"_ You've gotta help us out here - there are a few things that you've glossed over. GMail, for instance - does the attachment look OK in Gmail? And the import to the spreadsheet, please show your code for importing from GMail to a Google spreadsheet. Also why not show us a before and after example of a CSV file so we can see what the "junk" actually looks like.

Comment: The one way I figured out it is, added the extra commas to the first row. With this, I am able to open the attachment with proper data in Gmail (G sheet).

Comment: That’s good news.